# Cannot boot on windows 8 after installing Scientific Linux 6.5

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, grub, efi, scientific-linux

I had a standard toshiba latop (2014 model with EFI), which came pre-installeed with windows 8.1 and I tried to install Scientific Linux(SL) 6.5 in dual boot mode. Originally, I couldn't install it as is because anaconda could not shrink the existing windows partition and create a new one for linux. So, I did shrink the volume manually, from windows, where I split the windows partition in two. I had also to disable secure boot. Then I installed SL as usually, lvm, swap, etc.... GRUB was installed and SL, too. I was able to log onto SL without any problem. GRUB also realised the other operating system and created an entry under the /etc/grub.conf.

```
title Other
    rootnoverify (hd0,2)
    chainloader +1
```

However, when I tried to boot onto Other (Windows 8.1) that wasn't possible;
I received the message

```
invalid EFI file path
Error 1:Filename must be either an absolute pathname or blocklist
```

So, I had to change the /etc/grub.conf manually. I certainly found out that the partition was not the correct one, based on:

```
[root@unknown ~]# parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HTSXXXXXXXXX (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  ntfs         Basic data partition  hidden, diag
 2      1075MB  1180MB  105MB   fat32        Basic data partition  boot
 3      1180MB  1314MB  134MB   ntfs         Basic data partition  msftres
 4      1314MB  254GB   253GB   ntfs         Basic data partition
 6      254GB   255GB   524MB   ext4
 7      255GB   490GB   236GB                                      lvm
 5      490GB   500GB   9652MB  ntfs         Basic data partition  hidden, diag


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: 176GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  176GB  176GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: 6140MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  6140MB  6140MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: 53.7GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B

Partition Table: loop


Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  53.7GB  53.7GB  ext4
```

It seems that the GRUB was not very accurate, so I changed it to:

```
title Windows8
    rootnoverify (hd0,3)
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

I also tried

```
title Windows8
    rootnoverify (hd0,3)
    chainloader /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

However, the error I receive is:

```
Error 17: cannot mount selected partition
```

Other (trivial) info:

```
[root@unknown ~]# grub --version
grub (GNU GRUB 0.97)

[root@unknown ~]# uname -a
Linux unknown 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 19 14:01:59 CDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@unknown ~]# uname -a
Linux unknown 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 19 14:01:59 CDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@unknown EFI]# ls /boot/efi/EFI
Boot  Microsoft  redhat  Toshiba


[root@unknown ~]# ls /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
BCD           BOOTSTAT.DAT  en-US  hu-HU        nb-NO      ro-RO       tr-TR
BCD.LOG       boot.stl      es-ES  it-IT        nl-NL      ru-RU       uk-UA
BCD.LOG1      cs-CZ         et-EE  ja-JP        pl-PL      sk-SK       zh-CN
BCD.LOG2      da-DK         fi-FI  ko-KR        pt-BR      sl-SI       zh-HK
bg-BG         de-DE         Fonts  lt-LT        pt-PT      sr-Latn-CS  zh-TW
bootmgfw.efi  el-GR         fr-FR  lv-LV        qps-ploc   sr-Latn-RS
bootmgr.efi   en-GB         hr-HR  memtest.efi  Resources  sv-SE
```

I have tried also forums about centos, fedore, rhel... but not good luck either...

I have spent many hours, without any success. Any further ideas? I found several quick hacks, but these do not correspond to my case.

Do I need to install rEFInd? (I would like not to)

PS. some info is redundant, I just put them for pendantic purposes, in hope to help other users, too.

Any bit is highly appreciated and welcome

Many Thanks in advance,
Y

Comment: have you tried Boot-Repair-Disk? http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: Boot Repair is intended for Ubuntu. It might work, but it might make a bigger hash of things. I recommend you try rEFInd. You can do so with very little risk by trying the USB flash drive or CD-R version, available from its [downloads page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If that works, you can install the RPM version. Note that when you try it from USB or CD-R, you may need to hit F2 or Insert twice and add `root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` to have it boot. Once you install the RPM, this should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Scientific Linux 6.5 and Windows 7. However, I want to say rEFind works! Following the instruction at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html and use the install.sh in your linux environment. After rebooting, a similar page pops out http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/using.html (if you enter a key). Then you can select the OS you want.